# Round-Robin Iterator and STL's pass-by-value policy

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I'm writing an iterator `round_robin_iter` that keeps a bunch of iterators around. Whenever `round_robin_iter` is incremented, it increments the current iterator and passes on to the next one, in a circular manner. This allows me to easily interleave items from different containers. However, with a growing number of iterators, I can no longer use STL's algorithms with `round_robin_iter` because the STL likes to pass iterators by value with is expensive in this case.

My crude idea to solve this problem is to pass a `reference_wrapper<rouund_robin_iter>` by value to the STL algorithms, but this seems like a dirty hack to me. The STL surely provides some more elegant solution to my problem, doesn't it?

EDIT: as pointed out by HolyBlackCat, `reference_wrapper` doesn't implement the right interface, so I would have to write my own wrapper around an indirection to the `round_robin_iter`...

EDIT2: as requested, here's a rough skeleton of what the iterator may look like:

```cpp
template<class Iter>
struct round_robin_iterator
{
  using IterList = list<pair<Iter, Iter>>;
  using reference = typename iterator_traits<Iter>::reference;
  IterList others;
  typename IterList::iterator current = others.end();

  bool is_end() const { return current == others.end(); }

  void operator++() {
    if(!others.empty()) {
      if(++(current->first) == current->second)
        current = others.erase(current);
      else ++current;
      if(is_end()) current = others.begin();
    }
  }

  reference operator*() { return *(current->first); }

  void add_iters(const Iter& _begin, const Iter& _end) {
    others.emplace_back(_begin, _end);
    if(others.size() == 1) current = others.begin();
  }

  bool operator!=(const round_robin_iterator& rr_it) const {
    if(!is_end()){
      if(!rr_it.is_end()){
        return current != rr_it.current;
      } else return true;
    } else return !rr_it.is_end();
  }
};
```

Comment: `reference_wrapper` wouldn't work, since it doesn't overload the necessary operators. You could try putting the state of `round_robin_iter` into a `shared_ptr`, and implementing some kind of copy-on-write optimization (if the state is owned by a single iterator, then it can be modified directly, otherwise it has to be copied and then modified).

Comment: Are all the iterators contained in your `round_robin_iter` of the same type? If they are, can't you just put them in a `vector`?

Comment: @TedLyngmo How would that help? The vector would still have to be copied (expensive), no?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat putting the "state" somewhere on the heap might be an interesting way to make copies more efficient. I'd have to have a way to tell the iterator when to use a deep copy and when to use a shallow copy, but I might be able to wrap my head around that ^^

Comment: Putting the "state" somewhere on the heap is what the filesystem iterators do.

Comment: @igel "_The vector would still have to be copied (expensive), no?_" - If you really mean copy, then yes, that would be expensive. If you mean _move_, then no, moving a `vector` is cheap. It's hard to tell without looking at the code.

Comment: STL algorithms copies the iterators because they are supposed to work with copies of iterators. The reason is that algorithms should not modify your iterators while performing some action. The question is why your iterators are too heavy to be copied around? Are your iterators doing anything else than pointing and iterating?

Comment: @armagedescu yes, `round_robin_iter` has to keep a bunch of other iterators around

Comment: @TedLyngmo ah so instead of calling, for example, `sort(first, last)` I would call `sort(move(first), move(last))` so that their iterators are move-constructed? That's also a nice idea!

Comment: @igel Hmm, no, that's not what I meant, but I think I'd need to see what your current implementation does before digging any deeper into this. I may have misunderstood what you're doing.

Comment: @armagedescu But I see what you mean: if I don't need my iterator anymore, I should pass an rvalue reference to it, otherwise, I cannot avoid the (expensive) copy anyways.

Comment: @igel Like Difficult to tell much things because I don't know what the implementation is. In order to use move semantics, the functionalities that you use should be move aware. But an iterator in general case is nothing more than a wrapper to a pointer, that points to some member of  some kind of container. That's why passing the iterators by copy to STL algorithms is supposed to be a lightweight operation. Would be great if you add some more details of implementation.

Comment: A `vector` would be faster than a `list`.

Comment: If you know beforehand how many inner iteterators there are, you may be able to do some tricks with `std::tuple` to eliminate the need for any heap allocations

Comment: @MooingDuck I chose `list` to be able to O(1)-`erase` iteratos that arrived at their end because I wouldn't want to skip over all those in each "round". For this reason I discarded `tuple`s (the case that there is one very long range and many other short ranges kind of discouraged the `tuple`-thought for me)

Comment: @igel: Yes, but now your copy constructor takes `n` heap allocations, which is incredibly slow.  With `vector`, you'd have linear time removals, but 1 heap allocation.  MUCH faster.  With `tuple`, you have 0 heap allocations ever, but have to skip full lists, which makes iterating the last few items slower. It's almost certainly _far_ faster than the list though.

Comment: @MooingDuck That's a good point. Would you still stand by this assertion if I managed to avoid copies completely (such as the suggested `sort(move(begin), move(end))`)?

Comment: @MooingDuck wait a minute, copying an `std::list` does `n` allocations? Isn't that wasteful? I mean, it certainly is possible with 1 allocation, right? Can we assume for the sake of argument that my list has a smart `allocator` that can copy with a single allocation?

Comment: @igel: No. By definition, coping a `std::list` does _at least_ `n` allocations. It is wasteful. That's one of the (several) reasons you should virtually never use `std::list`. There's nothing an allocator can do to optimize that.  Use a `std::vector` (or rarely `std::deque`). They're virtually always faster.

Comment: Also, I've just noticed that since your iterator violates the rule of three, it's invalid if it's ever copied.  Your `current` iterator will refer to the copied-from's `others`, rather than it's own

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2fc869086f726c45 is a variant that uses a tuple, and supports iterators of different types that also point at different but similar types.

Comment: @MooingDuck wow, thanks for the good work on the tuple-version (looks nice, I'd maybe still force equal types in favor of not returning rvalues) and the note about invalid copying. I hadn't thought about that. It's another point in favor of vectors/tuples (vector index would be OK to copy).

Regarding custom allocators, I thought I could write a custom allocator that, in my list's copy constructor, I can tell to reserve space for `other_list.size()` items which the allocator will use-up first. That way, copying the list will make exactly one allocation. Maybe I misunderstood allocators oO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the very helpful comments to the question, I gathered the following for passing "heavy" iterators to STL algorithms:

- if I no longer need the iterator, then I'll move it (pass `std::move(iter)`)
- if I do still need the iterator then, by definition, I need 2 different such iterators at some point and thus, the copy cannot be avoided
- putting the "state" on the heap and doing a shallow copy seems to pretend to be a copy while really being a move (or worse, having side-effects like changing an iterator that I didn't touch)

---

On the discussion about which container to use to store the iterators, I've done some benchmarking with `std::accumulate` over `round_robin_iterators` with the following underlying containers (along with the strategy what to do about iterators that reached their end):

1. `std::list` (O(1)-erasing)
2. `std::vector` (O(n)-erasing)
3. `std::deque` (O(n)-erasing)
4. `std::vector` (O(n)-skipping)
5. `std::deque` (O(n)-skipping)

(apologies for not including the `std::tuple`-version in the benchmark, but I needed dynamic sizes)

The benchmark tests iterating over (a) 1 large (size Z) + many (X-1) small (size Y) ranges and (b) many (X) ranges of sizes progressively increasing (from Y to Z). No copies are made (indeed, I deleted the `std::list`-version's copy constructor + copy-assignment), iterators are passed by move. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/igel-kun/round_robin_iter) but the gist is the following:

- size of the stored objects has little to no impact on *relative* performance
- `std::list` is hard to beat in this setting, even when Y approaches Z
- `std::deque`(erase) beats `std::vector`(erase) for roughly X > 100
- (erase) almost always beats (skip)